# Problem with 'OR' on this SOQL?

Tags: soql, query

```
SELECT Id, F1, F2, F3, F4 FROM Account WHERE F1 = false AND F2 IN :list  OR ( F3 = '001' AND  F4 = '002');
```

This query throws this error:

**System.QueryException: unexpected token: OR**

If I put **AND**, it works okay. Why I cannot use OR on this query?

Comment: Showing us the actual code instead of a sanitized version would probably help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is `OR` takes a decision between two filters. So you need to define scope for `OR` with parentheses.

So your query will change to

```
SELECT Id, F1, F2, F3, F4 FROM Account WHERE (F1 = false AND F2 IN :list)  OR ( F3 = '001' AND  F4 = '002');
```

Or

```
SELECT Id, F1, F2, F3, F4 FROM Account WHERE F1 = false AND (F2 IN :list  OR ( F3 = '001' AND  F4 = '002'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parentheses to clarify if you want:

```
(A AND B) OR (C AND D)
```

or:

```
A AND (B OR (C AND D))
```